# setting postback trigger for button inside datalist inside updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, updatepanel, datalist

I have a fileUpload control and Button inside datalist which is inside UpdatePanel and user need to upload file using fileUpload control and button.How to add postback trigger for the button so that the selected files via fileupload get uploaded to server.

```
         <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel">
                    <ContentTemplate>

     <asp:DataList ID="dlComments" runat="server" Width="100%" 
                                      onitemcommand="dlComments_ItemCommand" DataKeyField="CommentID" 
                                      onitemdatabound="dlComments_ItemDataBound" >
                                 <ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblSnNo" runat="server" class="label-small-grey" Text='<%#Eval("CommentNumber") %>' ></asp:Label>
<label style="font-size:12px; font-style:normal"><%#Eval("CommentText") %></label>
              <textarea runat="server" id="txtaCommentText" style="resize:none;" rows="3" cols="3" class="form-control"  placeholder="Your Comments Here"></textarea><Br>
            <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUploadReply" multiple="true" runat="server" class=""   /></p><br>
            <asp:Button ID="btnPostReplyComment" CommandName="PostReplyComment" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Post" />

    </ItemTemplate>

                        </asp:DataList>
                   </ContentTemplate>



        <Trigger>
        </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

On codeBehind,

```
 protected void dlComments_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
if (e.CommandName == "PostReplyComment")
{

FileUpload fileUploadReply = (FileUpload)e.Item.FindControl("fileUploadReply");
 functionTOStoreCommetns();
     string filename = Path.GetFileName(fileUploadReply.FileName);
            fileUploadReply.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);
}


}
```

The files get uploaded if its not within datalist by adding PostBackTrigger to UpdatePanel
Please help to add post back trigger for the buttin

Answer (score 0):

In your DataList `ItemDataBound` event, do this:

```
protected void dlComments_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    FileUpload lFileUpload = (FileUpload)e.Item.FindControl("fileUploadReply");
    PostBackTrigger lTrigger = new PostBackTrigger();
    lTrigger.ControlID = lFileUpload.ID;
    UpdatePanel.Triggers.Add(lTrigger);
}
```

Comment: I did it but its throwing an error: A control with ID 'fileUploadReply' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel'

Comment: Are you controlling the visibility of the control or a DataList row or the DataList itself? If the control is not rendered, it won't be found.